# virus attacking address book and sending out bogus emails

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

a virus keeps attacking my addressbook and sends out bogus emails. What can I do. I've tried all the malwares and everything is "clean", however it keeps happening. What can I do?

Comment: David, follow the steps on this [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware), and update your question with more details of what worked, what didn't, if you need more help. If this other question is enough to fix your issue, don't hesitate to update as well, to tell that. @Sathya - this question is not made to close all virus-related questions as duplicates, it's only a reference. Every virus case is potentially different.

Answer (score 0):

Really the only thing you can do is eliminate the virus, there's tons of guides on this kind of stuff but the only truly sure way is to re-install windows.  Yeah it's an inelegant solution but it will fix the problem.  Good luck.